# gtest: Make base test class friend of the test class

Tags: c++, googletest, friend

I have the following constructs in my test:

```
class FooType {};
class OtherFooType {};

using FooTypes =
    ::testing::Types<FooType, OtherFooType>;

TYPED_TEST_CASE(FooTest, FooTypes);

template <typename FooClassType>
class FooTest : public testing::Test {

TYPED_TEST(FooTest, SimpleTest) {
```

I also have classes:

```
class Foo {

class OtherFoo : public Foo {
```

I would like to make `Foo` friend of `FooTest`.

I tried:

```
  template <typename FooTypes>
  friend class FooTest;
```

in the Foo class declaration, but the protected fields from Foo are still not visible from FooTest. What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. Making FooTest a friend class allows accessing private fields from methods inside FooTest, but not from the individual test cases. I had to add accessors in FooTest that would allow access into Foo.